# How to display randomly text when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, event-listener, buttonclick

I've got a project to do and I'm stuck at this stage. I have 5 paragraphs that include text and images that have to be displayed randomly in the button in clicked.  I still haven't figured out how to add the images in all of this. So far this is where I am:

```js
function myFunction() {
  idArray = new Array()
  idArray [1] = "First paragraph text"
  idArray [2] = "Second paragraph text
  idArray [3] = "Third paragraph text
  idArray [4] = "Fourth paragraph text"
  idArray [5] = "Fifth paragraph text"

  document.getElementById("select").onclick = myFunction;
  randomParagraph = Math.floor(Math.random()*5);

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = new Array[randomParagraph];       
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button onclick="myFunction()" id="select">Pick text</button>

  <div class="main">
    <p id="result"></p>
  </div>
  <footer class="footer">Hey</footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Why do you start indexing at `1`? `Math.floor(Math.random()*5)` will give you a number from `0` to `4`.

Comment: The `innerHTML` method expects a `string`, not an `Array`. Just change `document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = randomParagraph;`

Comment: @ElChiniNet I think, you are wrong. It should be `document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = idArray[randomParagraph]`

Comment: @Syntac Yes, you are right. I didn't notice that `randomParagraph`is an integer.

Comment: @ElChiniNet you wanna change it and i delete my comment?

Comment: No @Syntac, I think that the comments are important too ;)

Answer (score 0):

`new Array[randomParagraph];` does not work.

What you need to do is to access the value at the index form the idArray - `idArray[randomParagraph + 1]`

The +1 had to be added since the idArray you've defined goes from 1 to 5 while the random number generated goes from 0 to 4 since you are using `Math.floor`

Working example here:

```js
function myFunction() {
  idArray = new Array()
  idArray [1] = "First paragraph text"
  idArray [2] = "Second paragraph text"
  idArray [3] = "Third paragraph text"
  idArray [4] = "Fourth paragraph text"
  idArray [5] = "Fifth paragraph text"

  document.getElementById("select").onclick = myFunction;
  randomParagraph = Math.floor(Math.random()*5);

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = idArray[randomParagraph + 1];       
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button onclick="myFunction()" id="select">Pick text</button>
  <div class="main">
    <p id="result"></p>
  </div>
  <footer class="footer">Hey</footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Shortened**

```js
var text = [
  "First paragraph text",
  "Second paragraph text",
  "Third paragraph text",
  "Fourth paragraph text",
  "Fifth paragraph text"
];

document.getElementById("select").onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = text[Math.floor(Math.random() * text.length)];
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button id="select">Pick text</button>
  <div class="main">
    <p id="result"></p>
  </div>
  <footer class="footer">Footer</footer>
</body>
```